# PHP - How to eval math with big integer result?

Tags: php, eval, bigint

I have a problem like this
when i eval this

```
$a='820725059 + 35 * 4082615 + 6209777 - 6476390779 * 3376849 + 3 - 8089 * 3967379273 - 0 * 55111452';
eval('return ('.$a.');');
```

i got this result -2.1901884886788E+16
instead of -21901884886788304

i know about BCMath, but how to calculate multiple operation like this?

Note:
My problem is about print out as BIG INT

Comment: I think this might help http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: this is multiple operation, that i didn't know which would be appear first

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using 32bit or 64bit PHP

```
echo PHP_INT_SIZE; //4 is 32bit, 8 is 64bit
```

**32bit** won't handle this integer, for **64bit** the result is **-21901884886788304**

if you have to use 32bit, try using [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), and parse the integer yourself (good luck...)

Another solution is to write very basic Python program (or any other language that handles large numbers easily) and send it as an argument with [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and let the other language to parse it for you (Python can handle very large numbers easily)

Comment: i use ubuntu 64bit, and echo PHP_INT_SIZE; i got 8

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the line "how to calculate multiple operation like this?" means "how to write a calculator for arbitrary user-submitted math expressions?", which is why you use `eval` in first place.

If you use `eval` over unsanitized user-submitted input, you fail, remember this as a rule of thumb.

You just can't solve this with `eval` anyway, you have to use BCMath operations if you want to work with bignums.

Proper solution is to tokenize the input and construct the tree of math operations, essentially writing an interpreter for simple language for describing math expressions.

Here is result of 5 seconds of googling for something already done before: https://github.com/michellesanver/Calculator You can take her work and replace usage of plain math operators in classes like [`Addition`](https://github.com/michellesanver/Calculator/blob/master/Calculator/Operator/Addition.php) with BCMath methods.